# How to identify consecutive repeating values in data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I am trying to figure out how I can identify consecutive repeating values in a data frame column in python, and then be able to set a number for how many consecutive repeating values I am looking for. I will explain further here.

I have the following data frame:

```
DateTime                 Value         
-------------------------------
2015-03-11 06:00:00          1               
2015-03-11 07:00:00          1               
2015-03-11 08:00:00          1               
2015-03-11 09:00:00          1               
2015-03-11 10:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 11:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 12:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 13:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 14:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 15:00:00          0               
...
```

Now I have the following question: In the "Value" column, is there ever an instance where there are "2" or more consecutive "0" values? Yes! Now I want to return a "True".

Now I have this data frame:

```
DateTime                 Value         
-------------------------------
2015-03-11 06:00:00          1               
2015-03-11 07:00:00          1               
2015-03-11 08:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 09:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 10:00:00          1               
2015-03-11 11:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 12:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 13:00:00          0               
2015-03-11 14:00:00          1               
2015-03-11 15:00:00          1               
...
```

Now I have the following question: In the "Value" column, is there ever an instance where there are "3" or more consecutive "0" values? Yes! Now I want to return a "True".

And of course, if the answer is "No", then I would want to return a "False"

How can this be done in python? What is this process even called? How can you set this so that you can change the number of consecutive values being looked for?

Comment: What is the expected Output dataframe? Suppose you have more than 2 consecutive 0's. Which row will receive `True`?

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether).

Comment: Hey what happened with this question? Did my answer get you anywhere?

Comment: The expected output is simply a `True` or `False` indication. This would not be a matter of which row would receive the true. The output dataframe could contain a column that shows just 1 or 0, where 1 = True and 0 = False, and then the first row after the 2 consecutive 0's would receive the 0 value for False. Everything before that would be 1 for true, and everything after would be 0 for false. I accepted an answer, both suggestions gave the correct True or False output, but I ended up going with using a rolling window with the `df.rolling()` function. Thank you both for your awesome help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect consecutive runs in the series, we first detect the turning points by looking at the locations where difference with previous entry isn't 0. Then cumulative sum of this marks the groups:

```
# for the second frame
>>> consecutives = df.Value.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
>>> consecutives

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    4
7    4
8    5
9    5
```

But since you're interested in a particular value's consecutive runs (e.g., 0), we can mask the above to put `NaN`s wherever we don't have 0 in the original series:

```
>>> masked_consecs = consecutives.mask(df.Value.ne(0))
>>> masked_consecs

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    NaN
5    4.0
6    4.0
7    4.0
8    NaN
9    NaN
```

Now we can group by this series and look at the groups' sizes:

```
>>> consec_sizes = df.Value.groupby(masked_consecs).size().to_numpy()
>>> consec_sizes

array([2, 3])
```

The final decision can be made with the threshold given (e.g., 2) to see if *any* of the sizes satisfy that:

```
>>> is_okay = (consec_sizes >= 2).any()
>>> is_okay
True
```

Now we can wrap this procedure in a function for reusability:

```
def is_consec_found(series, value=0, threshold=2):
    # mark consecutive groups
    consecs = series.diff().ne(0).cumsum()

    # disregard those groups that are not of `value`
    masked_consecs = consecs.mask(series.ne(value))

    # get size of each
    consec_sizes = series.groupby(masked_consecs).size().to_numpy()

    # check sizes agains the threshold
    is_okay = (consec_sizes >= threshold).any()

    # whether a suitable sequence is found or not
    return is_okay
```

and we can run it as:

```
# these are all for the second dataframe you posted
>>> is_consec_found(df.Value, value=0, threshold=2)
True

>>> is_consec_found(df.Value, value=0, threshold=5)
False

>>> is_consec_found(df.Value, value=1, threshold=2)
True

>>> is_consec_found(df.Value, value=1, threshold=3)
False
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you can use .shift() to create a new column that has the same values as your column `Value`. Than

```
df["Value_shif"] = df["Value"].shift()
```

output:

```
              DateTime  Value  Value_shif 
0  2015-03-11 06:00:00      1         NaN    
1  2015-03-11 07:00:00      1         1.0  
2  2015-03-11 08:00:00      0         1.0   
3  2015-03-11 09:00:00      1         0.0
```

than you can compare them and get True/False:

```
df["Value"] == df["Value_shif"]
```

output:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
```

than Sum the number of repeating values:

```
df["count"] = (df["Value"] == df["Value_shif"]).cumsum()
```

cumsum() will treat `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`

output:

```
              DateTime  Value  Value_shif  count
0  2015-03-11 06:00:00      1         NaN      0
1  2015-03-11 07:00:00      1         1.0      1
2  2015-03-11 08:00:00      0         1.0      1
3  2015-03-11 09:00:00      1         0.0      1
```

if Sum is larger than 1 then you have consecutive repeating values.

Once you have this info you can filter the dataframe under specific conditions, check for specific `values` if the `number_of_times` it occurs is larger than a certain amount.

```
def check(dataframe, value, number_of_times):
    """
    Check for condition
    """
    df = dataframe.copy()
    df = df[df['Value'] == value]
    if df["count"].max() >= number_of_times:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

```
print(check(df, 1, 1))
True

print(check(df, 0, 3))
False
```

You'll need to check for specific boundary conditions to make sure everything works as intended. The problem with shift() is that it creates NaN as the first value and removes the last value from the column...

Comment: How do you determine if a specific value (e.g., 1) is repeated specific amount of times (e.g., 3)?